# warning: excess elements in array initializer

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to create 2D array.

```
int main() {
    int stalagmite[10][6] = { { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
                              { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
                              { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                              { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                              { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
                              { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 } };

    printf("%d\n", stalagmite[3][3]);
}
```

Output as follows:

```
deneme.c:9:51: note: (near initialization for ‘stalagmite[5]’)
deneme.c:9:54: warning: excess elements in array initializer
9 |                         { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 } };
```

Trying to define an array with initializer. When I try to compile it always return a error stated above. I tried to change size, data type but it had no effects.

Comment: The array, as you initialize it, has a dimension of `[6][10]`-- six rows of ten elements each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int stalagmite[10][6]` defines an array of 10 arrays of 6 `int`, whereas your initializer specifies 6 arrays of 10 integers.

The definition should probably be changed to `int stalagmite[6][10] = {...}` or possibly `int stalagmite[][10] = {...}`.

Comment: Thank you. I used your suggestion and fixed this problem.